# Cannot remove: {path}: Read-only file system

Tags: 18.04, windows, read-only

I am new to Ubuntu (currently only using it to delete a folder Windows won't let me delete). I am getting the error after typing `sudo rm -rf {path}` in the Terminal. How do I fix this? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

EDIT: I did not technically install Ubuntu, I made a bootable drive and selected "Try Ubuntu without installing".

Comment: If you are using it from a live USB you need to remount the file system as R/W because for security reasons it is mounted as only R. Did you do it before trying the command above?

Comment: Make sure Windows's "fast startup" is disabled